# Azure SSO OIDC ID_TOKEN, what causes email to return has "email protected"?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I'm looking for some hints has to why some users' `id_token` return the `email` and `preferred_username` claims in the `ID_Token` JWT  returning `"has email protected"`.

Comment: Where **exactly** are you seeing this? Did you decode the actual `id_token` or are you looking at it through a logging-system? I'm asking because I don't _yet_ see any signs that Azure Entra allows users or orgs to hide their users' contact email addresses from third-party RPs **but** the text `[email protected]` is a _very common_ substititon string used in front-end privacy screens and web-application firewalls to prevent inadvertent disclosure - and they can sometimes get-in-the-way of troubleshooting too when they unhelpfully modify a log entry screen...

Comment: I was seeing it on a clients machine in electron (chromium browser) dumped to the screen when trying to debug the issue. So your saying this might be something on their end doing a substitution in the html of the page.....

Comment: It's _possible_, yes. To find out for certain you'll need to get the _raw_ Base64-ish JWS-formatted `id_token` - copy-and-paste it into a (known-safe and trustworthy!) JWT/JWS decoder (VS2022 has one built-in now), but my personal go-to is https://jwt.io

Comment: This could have been caused by Cloudflare's Email Obfuscation setting. Since the client hasn't responded yet, I am unable to confirm this yet. But, I am highly suspecting that was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by Cloudflare's Email Address Obfuscation in the Scrape Shield section. Solutions to prevent this provided by Cloudflare's documentation. [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/tools/scrape-shield/email-address-obfuscation/)